# php get all matches string in text after "@" character

Tags: php, regex

I have this function that I want set text to return some match string from text :

```
function get_matches(){
    $string = "@text1 @text2 any text here #text3 #text4 @text5 ";
    // Set the test string.

    // Set the regex.
    $regex = 'WHAT IS THE REGEX HERE';

    // Run the regex with preg_match_all.
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

    // Dump the resulst for testing.
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

the Result :

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => text1
        [1] => text2
        [2] => text5
    ))
```

How can I write the Appropriate regex to get the right result.

Comment: What should be printed for `@text^#$*!& blah`? For `@   foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
$regex = '/@(\S+)/';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @text1
            [1] => @text2
            [2] => @text4
            [3] => @text5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text1
            [1] => text2
            [2] => text4
            [3] => text5
        )

)
```

Comment: How can we do it with one array I mean :

Array
        (
            [0] => text1
            [1] => text2
            [3] => text5
        )

Comment: @ghalyonline Just put a `$matches = array_merge($matches[1]);` before you print it!

Comment: Please can you tell me how can print result without "@".

Comment: @ghalyonline As i said just put the line: `$matches = array_merge($matches[1]);` after the preg_match_all line!

Comment: `(?<=@)\S+` will be more accurate, since the OP doesn't want to match `@` itself.